# RC circuit help

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

I saw in a book that U1 = U3 I mean if we apply kirchhof rule we get U1=U3 +Ur ?
or maybe its different because its a capacitor ?

[image]

Comment: Please draw the circuit

Comment: Ur goes to 0 after T>>RC

Comment: Hi! Welcome to EE.SE. Please use the schematic editor to draw the schematic. Your drawing is pretty much undecipherable

Comment: Please use schematic editor or some other proper tool to draw the circuit . Your circuit do not provide any information about U , is it voltage source or current source ? Is it DC or AC ? please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the SI unit of electrical potential difference is the volt, named in honor of Alessandro Volta,  and its abbreviation is 'V', not 'U'.

Second, since no steady-state current can flow through C1 or C2, or through R1, 
V1 will, indeed, be equal to V3.

Comment: Uhm... you just got upside down. Indeed 'V' is electrical potential unit, but those on the schematic are just symbols referring to some of its quantities.  So across R you may have a potential difference \$U_\text{R}=3\,\text{V}\$, or you may have choosen a different symbol, say \$X_\text{R}=3\,\text{V}\$. What instead is really strange is when we all write \$V_\text{R}=3\,\text{V}\$, we are using the unit as a symbol too.

Comment: Just try to do the same with a capacitor not \$C_1=100\,\mu\text{F}\$ but \$F_1=100\,\mu\text{F}\$ or with a resistance: not \$R_1=100\,\Omega\$ but \$\Omega_1=100\,\Omega\$. Weird isn't it? Actually voltage is the only quantity allowed this sharing.

Comment: @carloc: That's  all nonsensical  gobbledygook, since what you're espousing is that the use of randomly chosen symbols should be de rigueur in a scientific discussion, and that  the symbols  should be chosen, capriciously,  by the author, without regard to established convention or to  his readers.

Comment: Of course established convention are  preferred choice and by the way note that among them U for voltages is a quite common one. Then call it nonsense but if you think it over you'll find indeed **voltage is the only quantity allowed to be named as its unit**.

Comment: I live in germany and they use U thats why im used to

Comment: thank you for the answer but I still dont understand  since no steady-state current can flow through C1 or C2, or through R1, V1 will, indeed, be equal to V3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still care, but this question was bumped, so ... by definition, in steady-state, the circuit is in equilibrium and there are no changing voltages or currents.  To determine the steady-state condition, you would imagine the caps as open circuits.  That would result in a circuit with no current flowing through R, thus no voltage drop, so U1 = U3.  Put the caps back in and assume they will be charged to whatever voltage is present at the terminals in steady-state, which in the case of C1 is U1 = U3.